# How can I enable Google Maps to my enterprise users?

Tags: google-workspace, google-maps

We are using Google Enterprise. Usually, when I want to add/remvoe a core/other service it's done from the [Admin Control panel](http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&p=local&ctx=ch_b/0/ServiceNotAllowed&answer=182442)

Currently, when trying to access maps.google.com both me (Admin) and my users get the following error:

[image]

I am familiar with this procedure, however, within the entire list of Google Services. I can not see Maps/Google Maps or any other service with a similar name. The only think close to it is called: Places - I enabled that, but I don't think it's the service I need.

So, how do I enable Google Maps to my Enterprise users?

Comment: If I remember correctly, there was a somehow similar question around here—an activated Enterprise service did’t showed up—and it turned out you have to wait for a while (a few hours or so).

Comment: This can happen if I turn a service ON - It may take time to propagate to my users. However, the service ON/OFF options and the service itself is missing from the list of services - so even as Admin - I can't even change it's settings - let alone use it.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 1):

Google Maps is not available for Google Apps accounts that were not created with United States as country of organization.

Unfortunately, it is impossible to change country to an existing account, you must delete your google apps account (wait 3-5 days for it to purge from google's systems) and re-create it.

Comment: Do you have documentation links to support this answer?

Comment: I do not have actual documentation, this is based on information I got from the paid phone support by google

Answer (score 0):

I just had a case like this and decided to share my findings.

Use Chrome browser to avoid any unwanted errors:

1. Log in to admin.google.com
2. Click on 'Other Google Services', which may be located under 'More Controls'.
3. Click on the 'Filters' icon at the top right.
4. Uncheck 'Show top featured services'.
5. Search for 'Google Maps' on your page.
6. Toggle the service ON for the entire domain or sub-organization of your choice.

And Google Maps is available in US and in Google Apps. The Maps, just have a different Support.

Comment: We usually don't use signatures on SE, but if you are affiliated with the company, that's okay to mention.  It's not clear if that's the case here.